# fatal no pg_hba.conf entry error when using Heroku and Postgresql

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

I'm getting this error when pushing my Django project to Heroku:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 200, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 187, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "jkkflotmzeoxrq"
FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "54.171.72.104", user "jkkflotmzeoxrq", database "dcbe6ld5353s18", SSL off
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 85, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 92, in handle
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 53, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 216, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 77, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 55, in has_table
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 259, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 235, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 200, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 187, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "jkkflotmzeoxrq"
FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "54.171.72.104", user "jkkflotmzeoxrq", database "dcbe6ld5353s18", SSL off
```

I've looked at the postgres database that is attached to my heroku project and the credentials are not the same as displayed we have not made any changes to the database only the django project itself. Heroku was working up until like 10 days ago and now every time we push to heroku the deployment fails because of this error.

My settings.py file:

```
import os

import dj_database_url

from reportr.settings.local.email_settings import *
from reportr.settings.packages.aws_settings import *
from reportr.settings_base import *

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = get_env_variable("SECRET_KEY", )

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = int(get_env_variable("DEBUG", "1"))

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

INSTALLED_APPS.append('storages')

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases
DATABASES = {}
DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.parse(
    get_env_variable('DATABASE_URL'), conn_max_age=600)

MIDDLEWARE.insert(1, 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware')

MEDIA_URL = '/uploads/'

if os.getenv("EXTRA_STATICFILES_DIRS"):
    STATIC_ROOT = os.getenv("EXTRA_STATICFILES_DIRS")
    

ADMINS = []
for admin in get_env_variable('ADMINS', '-').split(", "):
    if admin:
        admin = tuple(admin.split(":", 1))
        if len(admin) == 2:
            ADMINS.append(admin)
```

Error after updating the database variable:

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/python
-----> Python app detected
-----> Using Python version specified in runtime.txt
-----> No change in requirements detected, installing from cache
-----> Using cached install of python-3.8.12
-----> Installing pip 21.3.1, setuptools 57.5.0 and wheel 0.37.0
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
celery 5.2.3 requires setuptools<59.7.0,>=59.1.1, but you have setuptools 57.5.0 which is incompatible.
-----> Installing SQLite3
-----> Installing requirements with pip
       Collecting setuptools
         Downloading setuptools-59.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (952 kB)
       Installing collected packages: setuptools
         Attempting uninstall: setuptools
           Found existing installation: setuptools 57.5.0
           Uninstalling setuptools-57.5.0:
             Successfully uninstalled setuptools-57.5.0
       Successfully installed setuptools-59.6.0
-----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
       Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
           main()
         File "manage.py", line 18, in main
           execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
           utility.execute()
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
           settings.INSTALLED_APPS
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 83, in __getattr__
           self._setup(name)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 70, in _setup
           self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 177, in __init__
           mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
           return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
         File "/tmp/build_fcfd3411/reportr/settings_prod.py", line 23, in <module>
           DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
       KeyError: 'default'
 !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
       See traceback above for details.
       You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
       Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
          $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

Comment: Are you connecting using the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps Heroku changed your credentials.  That would mean if you hard coded `DATABASE_URL` the password authentication would fail.  Resolution: run `heroku config` or visit your apps settings and select "Reveal Config Vars" to get the new credentials.

Here's the exert from the Heroku [docs](https://help.heroku.com/SMVK5PMS/why-have-my-heroku-postgres-credentials-changed):

> Occasionally we will roll Heroku Postgres credentials, this can happen
> for several reasons.
>
> Normally this is around maintenance or hardware failures but we also
> perform credential rolls for security reasons - typically this
> involves us setting the new configuration variable, DATABASE_URL for
> primary app databases, and restarting your application. This can cause
> issues if you have manually copy and pasted these credentials
> elsewhere, or have hardcoded them into your application.
>
> You can get the new credentials by running this command via the CLI:
> heroku config or visiting your app's Settings page and clicking the
> "Reveal Config Vars".

**Edit**
I see that you do indeed have the DATABASE_URL hardcoded, and it should NOT be.

Change

```py
DATABASES = {}
# This next line shows that you you are getting 
# the DATABASE_URL from your .env file, but this is
# what has changed, and is no longer valid.
DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.parse(
    get_env_variable('DATABASE_URL'), conn_max_age=600)
```

To *just*

```py
DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(default=get_env_variable('DATABASE_URL')), conn_max_age=600}
```

This should get the updated DATABASE_URL that Heroku generates.

**Edit 2**
I changed the above to deal with the DATABASE['default'] KeyError, but I see you also have a separate issue with running collectstatic.  Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41516097/10951070)

**Edit 3**
Is it possible you have more than one database attached?  Install the [Heroku CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli) if you don't have it already then

Run

```
heroku pg:info
```

That should list the databases.  Then promote the correct one, by running

```
heroku pg:promote HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_<COLOR>_URL -a example-app
```

Where example-app is the name of your app, and replace `<COLOR>` with the correct database.
Finally, destroy the unwanted databases with

```
heroku addons:destroy HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_<COLOR>
```

Where `<COLOR>` is the database you want destroyed.

**Another option is to delete the app, then re-add the postgres addon after you add the app in again.**

GOOD LUCK!

Comment: My Database_URL variable is set in the config but it appears to be incorrect to the postgresql database that is attached to the project. It won't let me update this with the new url as it says it cannot be overwritten?

Comment: You should not change the DATABASE_URL in the config, and Heroku stops you.  That config variable is set by Heroku, and can change.  It is an environment variable and should not be hard-coded in your code, but fetched using `dj_database_url`  I'm not sure what you mean by "...it appears to be incorrect to the postgresql database that is attached to the project".  Please add your settings.py.

Comment: Please see settings.py file contents attached in original question.

Comment: @J07D, I updated my answer.  I think it should work.  You do indeed have the DATABASE_URL hardcoded, and it should not be.

Comment: Thanks, updated but now getting an error in the build log. (See above)

Comment: Okay, @J07D, I think I see my error, and have edited my answer.  Hope this solves the error because I am pretty much out of ideas.  I also see you have another issue with the collectstatic.  Check out the link I added to that.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @raphel, I have sorted those errors however i am still seeing my original error in the release log in terms of the postgresql. Now it says my password authentication failed.

Comment: Sorry to hear that @J07D, I've edited my answer one more time with another possible solution. I don't know what else it could be.  Sorry.